# Webrtc video call screen goes black sometimes and app crashed

Tags: android, webrtc

In lower resolution device most of the time screen goes black while rendering the view. Got the below error as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: glUseProgram: GLES20 error: 1285
at org.webrtc.GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error(GlUtil.java:29)
at org.webrtc.GlShader.useProgram(GlShader.java:117)
at org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer.prepareShader(GlRectDrawer.java:198)
at org.webrtc.GlRectDrawer.drawYuv(GlRectDrawer.java:152) org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.renderFrameOnRenderThread(SurfaceViewRenderer.java:492)
at org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer.access$000(SurfaceViewRenderer.java:38)
at org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer$1.run(SurfaceViewRenderer.java:109)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I find out the issue in the given method for creating local media stream before connecting call.

```
public void createMediaStream(final EglBase.Context renderEGLContext,   final VideoRenderer.Callbacks localRender, final boolean isAudioCallOnly) {
    this.localRender = localRender;
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createMediaConstraintsInternal();
            if (mediaStream != null)
                return;
            mediaStream = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
            if (videoCallEnabled) {
                factory.setVideoHwAccelerationOptions(renderEGLContext, renderEGLContext);
                String cameraDeviceName = CameraEnumerationAndroid.getDeviceName(0);
                String frontCameraDeviceName =
                        CameraEnumerationAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();
                if (numberOfCameras > 1 && frontCameraDeviceName != null) {
                    cameraDeviceName = frontCameraDeviceName;
                }
                AppData.showLogMessage("Opening camera: "+ cameraDeviceName);
                videoCapturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(cameraDeviceName, null, peerConnectionParameters.captureToTexture ? renderEGLContext : null);
                if (videoCapturer == null) {
                    reportError("Failed to open camera");
                    return;
                }
                mediaStream.addTrack(createVideoTrack(videoCapturer));
               // videoToggle(isAudioCallOnly);


            }

            mediaStream.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack(
                    AUDIO_TRACK_ID,
                    factory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints)));


        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Tell us more about your project ( about android / webview versions) . Did you use webGL ? Post your code related to the error log. Probably you use webview .

Comment: I am using android org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer

Comment: Actually I create my project with the help of multiple webRTC code available at github. Do you know the reason while I am getting this. As well as some time shows black screen while setup media and app goes to ANR before connecting a call.

Comment: This bug is opengles error ( err : 1285 ) but i guest you are not using opengles in your code . https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=3031 . Best way is to use example from google android examples site !

Comment: I am using surface view renderer here and it uses opengles.

Comment: No webiew. I am using org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer for rendering the video.

Comment: @KaushikChatterjee Are you able to resolve it.

Comment: Yes, I had already updated my webrtc version.